# Variables con Kotlin

Tags: variables, kotlin

Estoy intentando completar una url por medio de variables pero al pasarlo y añadirlo a la url a la que quiero conectar me da error

```
override fun onCreate
    var mparam = intent.getStringExtra("param")

object Detalles {
        const val COD_INFO: String = mparam
    }

interface ApiActaPartido {
                 @GET("My_url"+COD_INFO)
                 fun getActaPartido(): Call<ActaPartidoList>    
            }
```

mparam me marca en rojo: initialiter should be a constan value

como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70930/discussion-between-rafel-c-f-and-lois6b).

Answer (score 0):

En Kotlin, [`const`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#compile-time-constants) sirve para marcar constantes **cuyo valor es conocido en tiempo de compilación**.

Eso significa que el valor de `mparam` debería ser conocido en tiempo de compilación. Tú obtienes ese valor en tiempo de ejecución, con un `Intent`, supongo.

La solución que se me ocurre es desmarcar `COD_INFO` como constante en tiempo de compilación y dejarlo así:

```
val COD_INFO : String = mparam
```

Comment: Ya lo prove y no funciona, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el object que estas creando es para acceder a la variable desde alguna otra clase, yo lo haría de la siguiente manera

object

```
companion object { lateinit var COD_INFO: String }
```

onCreate

```
COD_INFO = intent.getStringExtra("param")
```

y despues en la funcion que quieres llamar ambos

```
val x = "My_url$COD_INFO"
```

Espero te funcione.

Comment: Ya lo prove pero no va